# Two versions of the same dll in different projects

Tags: .net

[image]

I have a solution with multiple projects. There is a need that I have to refer a different version of the same assembly in two different projects. As of now what is happening is that only the latest version of the dll is getting copied into the bin folder. So the dll that depends on the older version fails with an error

```
Could not load file or assembly xxxx or one of its dependencies.
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the 
assembly reference.
```

Is there a way to get the application to use a specific version of dll based on the project?

Comment: welcome to the dll hell

Comment: Please provide more information on which executable needs which dll in which version. Are they all in the same directory? Can you use regasm and the assembly cache? A small example or graph will help much to help you solving this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can have each project reference a specific version of the same dll.  I would suggest putting both versions of the dll in the GAC.  In your referencing projects set the Copy Local = false  and Specific Version = true.

You could do it without the GAC by using your config file and [assembly binding directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3.aspx) (since the shared dlls can't be in the same folder because they have the same name) but this is one of the main problems the GAC was designed to solve.  So I would recommend taking advantage of it.

Comment: It should be mentioned that GAC is the correct solution only if the assemblies have a strong name (= are signed).

Comment: @developer747: Just to clarify, I was talking about config directives like Probing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb.aspx).  I was not talking about using bindingRedirect because that would actually not solve your problem.  bindingRedirect would cause both your assemblies to use the same version of the shared dll not different versions as you stated you needed.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys%28v=vs.100%29.aspx actually solved my problem. It is working as expected.

Comment: @developer747: Well that means that both of your projects will be using the same dll.  If that's what you want, why not just point them both at the same dll to begin with?  It sounds like you are saying that you need two projects to reference two different versions of the same dll but at runtime they can both run with the same version of the dll.

Comment: Project B is a shared project. Based on the diagram above, project B has a reference to a dll which I don't want to use in the current solution. At the same time I don't want to modify the references in project B because it is being used by other projects in other solutions. Using the config setting, I tell the app that hey even though there are multiple versions of this dll present, use this version.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your audience (if this is a server app, website, desktop app for a single user, desktop app for many users, etc.), you may be able to cheat a little and host one version in a totally separate app domain, like a web service or WCF service.

For example, assuming your project is a web application:

```
MyWebApplication
    - DLL reference to MyLibrary v1.0
    - Only have internal references which use v1.0 of the library
    - WCF proxy to http://localhost/MyWebService

MyWebService
    - DLL reference to MyLibrary v2.0
    - Only have internal references which use v2.0 of the library
```

Comment: @Alex The question does not distinguish what the audience of the application is - if it is a web application, and they are in a position to add a WCF service, then this solution will work - I've had to do this for this exact reason once. You may have to shuffle a few classes around, maybe generate some service wrappers, but it is definitely a potential solution, by keeping code which needs one version in the domain of the service, and code that needs the other version in the domain of the web app. GAC is potentially better depending on the scenario, but this is just another alternative.